# Can nbviewer render interactive widgets in a Jupyter notebook (using ipywidgets)?

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, nbviewer

I created an interactive widget in Jupyter lab using Ipywidgets interact() class. The widget allows you to select a column from a dataframe to visualise, it then displays a plotly plot of that column. The widget works as intended in Jupyter lab. When I push the notebook to github then view the notebook on nbviewer (see it [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/rhart-rup/London-Venue-Hire-Price-Prediction/blob/master/price_modeling/min_spend_modeling.ipynb) in cell 5) I cannot see the widget, instead all I see is the text below:

*interactive(children=(Dropdown(description='col_selected', options=('time_period_desc_fixed', 'price_type', 's…*

I wanted the widget to be visible and interactive on nbviewer i.e. wanted a user to be able to select different columns to visualise with a drop down.

I tried the following:

- I ensured that 'Save widget state automatically' setting was switched on in Jupyter lab and saved the file with the working widget before pushing to github.
- I tried converting the notebook to html with both nbconvert from command line and with the Jupyter lab export as html option. The html file had the interactive drop down available but it did not show the plots, but rather it showed unrendered html code, presumably of the plots.
- I tried using Jupyter Notebook and the 'Save Widget State' option then pushing to git.

```
jupyterlab 3.6.3
ipywidgets 8.0.6
```

Comment: Most ipywidgets-based use require an active Python kernel. What you see in cell #5 is typical. There are ways to do this that would work in nbviewer, but not with ipywidgets. For example, plotly plots are mostly javascript based once they are made and so the underlying interactions usually work in nbviewer. Alternatively, you can use Web Assembly-based Python, Pyodide kernel, and it will work from 'static' hosting sites to still render ipywidgets that work. Go [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and choose 'Try it with JupyterLab' and then when it opens choose 'pyodide' ...

Comment: <continued> folder in the file navigator on the left. Then double click to open the 'interactive-widgets.ipynb` notebook from the list of available demos. Run the cells. The Python backing the active notebook is running inside the browser so you don't need to host a server and you can use free or lowcost hosting such as Github spaces to provide active notebooks. There's even [Voici](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voici) that is JupyterLite+Voila so you can have apps without users seeing the code; it is though in preview & so not quite mature all round yet. And yet another alternative...

Comment: <continued> to continue to use ipywidgets is to use MyBinder sessions to serve your notebook or Voila rendering (app-based version of the same notebook). You can see an example by going [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/tree/master) and choosing 'launch binder'. When the session opens choose the third, fourth, or fifth notebooks listed as available to see ipywidgets-based use in action. The 'streamlined 3D scatter plot in Voila interface' will give you the Voila rendering of ...

Comment: <continued> [this notebook](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_Voila_matplotlibSTREAMLINED.ipynb).

Comment: Thanks for your help, sounds like quite a lot of extra effort to get it set up. I was hoping I was one small tweak away from easily adding to nbviewer, but seems ipywidgets isn't designed for that. I think in my case I'll probably opt for extracting the ipywidgets html and previewing it in a separate file. Thanks for your help

Comment: Good point; I forgot to mention that direction to pursue. Without conversion though prior, there isn't the support infrastructure for the widgets to work in nbviewer. In addition to Plotly working mostly in nbviewer, I should have added the animation controller that gets made when used with `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` works though in nbviewer without doing that step to the whole notebook because there's HTML encoding steps targeting the animation, see [here](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/d862333d8eefb94a74a79022840680b1). I don't know if you can 'wrap' ipywidgets similarly.